# Set charset through htaccess to a specific folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, character-encoding

I was wandering if it is possible to add charset to the root folder but then make an exception to a subfolder using htaccess?

As it is now I am setting the charset in my htaccess like this:

AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1

But this is made for the whole site/root.

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another `.htaccess` file in that specific folder and set specific charset there the same way you have it for the root folder. This is an example for UTF-8:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: That was simple... Thanks :-)

Comment: @Mansa Works? Please set it as a solution :) Thank you!